# How can I test Python virtual code environments programatically?

Tags: python, virtualenv, cicd, python-venv

We manage a significant number of Python virtual code environments in our estate. We are moving to a more aggresive OS level patching schedule which means there is higher risk to break some Python virtual code environments due to some OS level dependencies changing or issues during installation. We are therefore looking at different options to try to mitigate this risk. Aside from recreating the virtual code environment after OS patching what else can we do to confirm the code environment it's working fine? Of course running the code/app/model that the code environment is meant to support would be ideal but this is not practical/possible for various reasons that are not relevant to the question.

I was thinking that perhaps I could look at the requirements.txt of each virtual code environment and attempt to import all packages that required to be installed in each virtual code environment. From previous experience the majority of virtual code environment issues happen either during the creation of the code environment (ie when packages are installed/code env created) or when the required packages are imported in code. So this approach will cover most of the risk leaving only potential run time issues which should be a very small proportion.

What's you view on this approach? Do you see any issues with it? One thing I know will be a challenge is that package names don't always match the "import" name used in code but I suspect we will be able to work around this problem building a dictionary of package names and import names.

Comment: How are you testing that a new version of the code itself works, independent of possible virtual-environment changes? In some sense, there is no distinction between the virtual environment and the code at this level of testing: changes to either could break the deployment, so they need to be verified *together*.

Comment: In the scenario only the OS and OS level packages will change. The virtual environment and the code that uses it will remain the same (to the best of our ability as in freezing packages etc). Code testing will be done at a different time where OS and OS level packages are not changing. While in theory you are right it's common practice to decouple infrastructure changes from code changes to reduce risk and avoid having too many changes where you don't know what caused a problem.

Comment: Keep them decoupled, but recognize that a change in *either* can be validated using the same tests.

Answer (score 0):

## Process

I believe this should be done in a two step procedure

1. Create environment for testing (OS / Python Version)
2. Run a set of integration tests to determine `pass` state

Step `1` ensures you can create a environment which accurately represents what will be used in production.

Step `2` ensures you can test the environment and make sure it does what you expect.

Then all you have to do is repeat this procedure for each environment, adding  additional tests as you see fit.

## Creating an environment

This can be done in many ways:

1. Docker containers
2. Virtual machines using IaC provisioning
3. Manual config (not repeatable)

Manual config is not repeatable and would be slow.

## Running Integration Tests

This is dependent on what you are testing but could be done with

1. Bash / Python Scripts
2. Web API calls
3. File discovery
4. Other low level system calls

Comment: As an overall process the answer is correct. But I was looking for more specific details on exactly how I test virtual code environments is actually functional without actually running the relevant code that uses it. In a nutshell I am looking for some sanity checks before the final testing is done using code.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to define a few integration tests, something that should and should not happen. It may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you update Python, of course you might end up with versioning issues. if these are dev machines, I'd strongly suggest you enforce a policy to update, but not push it on the dev without their knowledge.

If you don't upgrade Python, the only things that may break are the packages that are not pure python and depend on those OS level packages. Even then, most of those will have been compiled at installation and unless they dynamically load OS libraries that changed APIs after patching, they would not be affected.
So you are left with identifying python packages that have dynamic OS-level library dependencies, and focus on those. There is likely only a few projects that would belong in that category, and they are usually the ones causing developers installation problems, so they should be easy to identify ;-)

You can use `pip inspect` to get a full description of the packages and the location of their metadata

You can go list files in the `site_packages` folders and find out which project were built from non-python source that may require OS level libraries, and focus on trying to install those after patching.

If you don't want to sweat it and automate this, a full `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will give you all of the packages in the environment, and a simple test would be to re-create the environment and `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Beyond that, I'd assume developers will be in charge of making the code and dev environment work, and hopefully they use some reproducible environment for deployment (like containers) and local OS patching of their dev machine will be annoying but won't affect prod immediately.

If you're now talking about patching live servers that are not containerized, then definitely follow a pattern of patching in dev, then staging before pushing those changes to prod. Let the code base go through all the testing they normally do through on those patched OSs, and let the devs iron out the bugs for the environments. When and if it becomes more important that you push an OS patch immediately rather than to go through a full test cycle, then you can take that decision.

Comment: "So you are left with identifying python packages that have dynamic OS-level library dependencies, and focus on those. You can go list files in the site_packages folders and find out which project were built from non-python source that may require OS level libraries, and focus on trying to install those after patching." => This is interesting, thanks! How would I identify non-python source that may require OS level libraries?

Comment: non python source is pretty easy to spot: files with .c, .cpp extensions to begin with. Now, which ones rely on OS Libraries: I think again the dev will know best. Let them patch their dev env OS and figure the libraries to upgrade, then push things down the stage/test/prod pipelines.